# Failed to connect facebook via my android app

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

i am trying to log in into facebook via my android app by following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started   At the end of this tutorial its show how to build app with simple facebook login. I do every step but get error in my phone. the error is that

```
invalid key hash.The key hash uqq53psgdtq.... does not match  any stored key hashes at 
http://developers.facebook.com/apps/my_app_id
```

but i check and recheck my key hash which i found by running keytool command in cmd on my pc. The key hash which is showed in the error is not my key hash. I don't know where that key hash come from.
Please any one please help me how this problem overcome? please please...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to get your correct `key hash` and use that key in the project created in `facebook developers site`

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.your_package_name",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("YOURHASH KEY:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

here `Log.d` will display `key hash` value in your `LogCat`.